# High Availability Error “An error occurred while receiving data: '10054(An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)'.”

Tags: high-availability, sql-server-2014

I have trouble in configuring High Availability, I searched a lot but I was unsuccessful in fixing it.

I got this error : "An error occurred while receiving data: '10054(An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)'."

I have 3 nodes in implementing AlwaysOn , One of them is Domain Controller and the others have implemented as Failover Clustering.
I configured firewall and windows authentication permission for all nodes but I have gotten the error yet.

Does anybody have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
my problem was installed same instance name.

Comment: Please provide more information. I am also facing similar issue.